# Externals do SVN no Git. Existe?

Tags: git, svn

Tenho uma camada comum em meu projeto que servirá para duas ou mais empresas.
Sei que no `SVN` existe a opção **Externals** em que referencio um repositório externo no repositório da empresa em questão.

Existe essa funcionalidade no Git?

Comment: Talvez você queria algo parecido com isto: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule ?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor prática é: publicar essa parte externa, dll, lib, framework, etc..., em algum lugar e utilizar o "compilado", entre aspas pois não necessáriamente é um objeto compilado; no seu código.
Por exemplo: Você está desenvolvendo um software em módulos, e faz um framework que será consumido nos módulos. A ideia é reaproveitar código, porém referenciando diretamente o código em cada módulo você irá recompilar toda a árvore, enquanto que, publicando o objeto, por exemplo, em um Nuget server, você fará o controle de versão no objeto compilado e consumirá no seu código. No próximo módulo você consumirá a mesma versão, não sendo necessária a recompilação dessa parte do código.

Se o seu código não precisar de compilção, publicar em um servidor de pacotes irá ajudar a manter as referências corretamente, sendo versionadas e distribuidas a partir de um ponto central.